# 32 bit DTrace on OSX

Tags: macos, dtrace

I need to run DTrace on 32-bit executables on OSX.  I have two machines, both running OSX 10.8.2.  On one of them, `/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib` is a fat binary, on the other it isn't:

```
/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

vs

```
/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Where do these two come from?  How do I get the fat one "officially", i.e. without just copying it over from the other machine?

This is what happens when I try to run dtrace on a 32-bit executable with the 64-bit only dylib, btw:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTrace library on Mac OS X ML is the fat binary (i386, x86_64). Your second machine lacks 32bit because someone removed it. Probably one of that system "optimizers" was run on the system.

SHA (`shasum /usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib`) of the lib on my machine is `0722f971d9999245cda234ba5fd3119820fa348a`. I've tested it on a few other machines and it matched. It also matched on a machine with fresh installation of Mac OS X ML. That means it's OK to just copy it.

The only other way to restore it is to either restore it from backup or reinstall the system.

Comment: What kind of optimizer would do that?  It's a very new machine, and I've never knowingly run such a thing.

Comment: oh you know that removes "unused" localizations in order to optimize disk space. I'll try to find "clean" system and update the answer.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that I've never (knowingly) run such a program, and this a machine that's a week old.

Comment: @MarkProbst Have you checked other binaries on the system?

Comment: Everything in /usr/lib seems to be as it should (compared to the other machine), except /usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib, which is also only x86_64, whereas on my other machine it, too, is fat.  It might be relevant that the older machine with the fat binaries was updated from 10.7, whereas the new, x86_64-only machine shipped with 10.8.

Comment: @MarkProbst I had installed Mac OS X 10.8.2 (from the AppStore) in VM and the binaries these binaries were fat.

Comment: Yeah, same here.  My machine that shipped with 10.8.2 (12C3103) has a 64-bit-only `libtrace_dyld.dylib`; another machine I upgraded has both a 32- and 64-bit version (12C60).  Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Interesting. I've tested this on MBA with preinstalled Mac OS X 10.8 and libtrace_dyld.dylib was fat.

Comment: Just wanting to add that both a recent iMac and a MBP Retina Display (early 2013) came with libdtrace_dyld.dylib thin for me.